# Blender Status Bar

Tags: screencast

first time poster here.

Using a 1920 screen the blender status bar, plus all notifications run off the screen to the point I cannot see key notifications (the little blue information box)from tools such as Boxcutter and Hardops. A real nuisance when trying to control the amount of bevels etc.

Does anybody know how I can have the status bar sized correctly to my screen please.

Comment: You can drag the contents left and right with the middle mouse button/wheel. Hover the cursor over the status bar, hold down the mouse wheel and drag the bar sideways.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I didn't know about the left/right drag option. It doesn't unfortunately get me closer to resolving the issue when interacting with HardOps. If I use Blender 2.83.7 the 'Information box' is on the left hand side, this interacts perfectly with the middle mouse wheel when adding bevels to booleans through HardOps for example. In later releases of Blender the Information bar is now on the right side. Now when I use HardOps and try to add Bevels to Booleans the number of Bevels slides off the screen. So now not sure if this is a Blender issue or Hardops?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by the 'Information box'. The HardOps settings can be got to by clicking the tab on the RHS of the 3D View window or from the little down-arrow just to the right of the Object menu in both Blender 2.83.9 and 2.90.1. An image of your problem would be useful!

Comment: Hi John, link to image of error here: https://imgur.com/a/kfJhXRK you can see the blue box running off the screen (bottom right) it only happens when I add a bevel to a boolean in Hardops, Problem does not occur in Blender 2.83.7 as the box is on the Left hand side, at 2.90 it has moved to the right.

Comment: Strange! I see this in both versions:  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rg81v3i519psma9/HardOps%20status.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: I think we are getting closer to the problem, your screen is how most tutorials show the behaviour of say boxcutter, for some reason mine defaults to the bottom bar. I think I may go over to the Boxcutter forum and ask a question, really appreciate your time.